# Changing network computer name

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking

I can't find a simple tutorial how to change my computer name under which is it visible on the network (Ubuntu 12.04). It's quite simple on Windows 7 but it looks like there's no such an option on Linux.

PS.
I mean only NETWORK NAME - I don't want to change domain visible in terminal (eg. Robin@Ubuntu).

Answer (score 7):

On Linux the network name which is visible in a Windows network is set in the configuration of the samba package. This normally resides in /etc/samba/smb.conf where you can add a line like "netbios name = mycomputer" just below the line "[global]".